# htaccess запретить вызов файлов

Tags: .htaccess

Как запретить вызов всех php файлов в папке кроме index.php с помощью htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно запретить вызов всех php-файлов, разрешив только `index.php`,то это решается так:

```
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "index.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Если нужно разрешить вызов `index.php` и `/`, то подойдёт такой вариант:

```
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "^(index\.php)?$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```